# Дрожжание объектов в юнити игре(по типу геометри дэш)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Описание проблемы: Я прикрепил камеру к игроку, игнорируя ее по оси Y, а игрок плавно перемещается с помощью rb Velocity, камера следует за ним также плавно, но объекты справа, думаю, все знают какие - шипы, стены, платформы, имеют микроджиттер какой-то.. в то же время нет, они не двигаются и они статичны. Я убрал все трения, которые нашел, в том числе и на физических материалах, изменение кода отслеживания камеры, как и движения игрока, не помогло. Единственное, что частично помогло, так это анализ в обновлениях, для плеера использую FixedUpdate, для отслеживания камеры LateUpdate. Так же немного помогло во вкладке rb плеера выставить Interpolate на Interpolate. И, проверил фпс - от 50 до 80. Помогите... сижу уже 7 дней